# Как хранить информацию для справочника на Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, dart, flutter

Делаю справочник на Flutter под Android, в нём есть раздел оказания первой помощи, каждый пункт ведет на страницу с инструкцией. Инструкции однотипны: симптомы, действия, риски, препараты - все представляют из себя списки с текстовыми полями, но проблема в том, что в каждом конкретном случае количество позиций списка разнится.

Как можно организовать хранение информации?

Склоняюсь к sql lite, но не знаю как в этом случае реализовать структуру. Также наверное можно каждую инструкцию хранить как html файл (создать шаблон и просто наполнять его), но в этом случае этих файлов будет большое количество и не думаю что такой подход верный

Comment: Sqlite или realm. Структура ключ значение. Либо одна таблица с названием помощи и у каждого названия колонка с ключом для другой таблицы итд

Comment: Если мало опыта с sqlite (для android сейчас приоритетнее использовать библиотеку Room) Начните изучать Realm, он попроще для начинающего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если информация будет храниться локально то [SQLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite). Если планируется на сервере, рекомендую [Firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database).

Realm на Flutter нет, и в ближайшие время не будет.

UPD: Появился аналог Room на Flutter: [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor#-readme-tab-), [moor_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter#-readme-tab-)

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, для Flutter нет Realm. Для SQLite библиотека:

https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Ну и если захочется файлами - все же легче будет в JSON делать.